# Eliminar un Command Button con otro Command Button - Visual Basic - Office Professional Plus 2010

Tags: vba, vb, ms-word, visual-basic

Estoy creando 5 command buttons en una plantilla de word, los primeros 4 están programados para insertar texto de otros documentos, pero puede que en una ocasión sólo se necesiten 2 botones, en otra que se usen 3, o incluso puede haber casos donde sólo se use 1.

Lo que busco es que independientemente de los botones que se usen, el botón 5 siempre pueda eliminar los que restan.

Los 5 botones los guardé como CB1, CB2, CB3, CB4 y CB5 (este es el que borra todo)

[image]

Intenté usando algo como lo siguiente para cada botón:

```
Public Sub CB5_Click()     
  
        CB1.Select
        Selection.Delete

End Sub
```

Pero digamos que si solo uso el tercer botón (CB3) y quiero borrar los restantes con CB5 (incluyendo el mismo CB5), puede que borre los primeros dos (CB1 y CB2), pero se detiene en CB3 y ya no borra el cuarto y el quinto botón (CB4 y CB5).

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. En vez de borrarlos, prueba a ocultarlos y jugar con la propiedad `Visible`. De esa manera no tienes que estar creando o borrando, solo ocultando o no. Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de otra manera, usando **On Error Resume Next** para continuar la ejecución a pesar de que no encontrara los botones usados.

Ejemplo:

```
CB1.Select
Selection.Delete
On Error Resume Next
```

y con eso :)